# How to perform edit action in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There are already a normal scaffolding for CRUD in Asp.net MVC but i am using my own code for saving the post.

**Abstract.cs(Model)**

```
public class Abstract
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser Member { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AbstractTitle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AbstractAim { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(300)]
    public string AbstractDetails { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public string CoAuthor { get; set; }

}
```

**AbstractController.cs**

```
public class AbstractsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public AbstractsController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(AbstractFormViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View("Create", viewModel);

        var memberId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var member = _context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == memberId);
        var abs = new Abstract
        {
            Member = member,
            AbstractTitle = viewModel.AbstractTitle,
            AbstractAim = viewModel.AbstractAim,
            AbstractDetails = viewModel.AbstractDetails,
            Author = viewModel.Author,
            CoAuthor = viewModel.CoAuthor

        };
        _context.Abstracts.Add(abs);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

}
```

This is my controller and model. Here i am trying to implement my own way to perform edit and update stuffs.
Here i am really confused how to perform edit stuffs for this create action.

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var customer = _context.Abstracts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

        if (customer == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        var memberId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var member = _context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == memberId);
        var viewModel = new Abstract
        {
            Member = member,
            AbstractTitle = viewModel.AbstractTitle,
            AbstractAim = viewModel.AbstractAim,
            AbstractDetails = viewModel.AbstractDetails,
            Author = viewModel.Author,
            CoAuthor = viewModel.CoAuthor

        };

        return View("CustomerForm", viewModel);
    }
```

But this isn't working please suggest or provide me a solution to write a edit action.

Comment: Why are you not using `AbstractFormViewModel` for your `Edit()` method?

Comment: And what is not working? (and I assume `db.Entry(Abstract).` is a typo and is really `db.Entry(abstract).` - ditto in `return View` in both methods.

Comment: Put your code in the question, not comments (its impossible to read especially when you don't format it)

Comment: Seems that `db.Entry(Abstract).State = EntityState.Modified` possibly throwing error during entity modification. You can use `AbstractFormViewModel` in `Edit` method to fill `Abstract` model before using `EntityState.Modified`.

Comment: In the GET method, initialize a new `AbstractFormViewModel()` and set its properties based on the data model and pass that view model to the view (its just the opposite if what you do in the `Create` POST method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this , Put your varibales and model in it

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id, EMP objmodel)
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
        {
            int j = Convert.ToInt32(id);

            EMP e =(EMP) db.EMPs.Single(n => n.id == j);
            //Either use Single(), SingleorDefault(), First(), FirstorDefault()
            return View(e);

        }
        else if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            if (objmodel.Name != null && objmodel.Email != null && objmodel.DOB != null)
            {
                //db.EMPs.AddorUpdate(objmodel);//requires using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
                db.EMPs.Attach(objmodel);
                db.Entry(objmodel).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.alert = u1.AlertDismissable("alert-success", "Record Updated successfully");
                TempData["alert"] = u1.AlertDismissable("alert-success", "Record Updated successfully");
                //return View("ShowAll", db.EMPs.ToList());
                return RedirectToAction("index", db.EMPs.ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.alert = u1.AlertDismissable("alert-danger", "No record Gets Updated , Maybe some fields are Empty");
                TempData["alert"] = u1.AlertDismissable("alert-danger", "No record Gets Updated , Maybe some fields are Empty");
                return View();
            }
        }

        ViewBag.alert = u1.AlertDismissable("alert-success", "Record added successfully");
        TempData["alert"] = u1.AlertDismissable("alert-success", "Record added successfully");
        //return View("ShowAll", db.EMPs.ToList());
        return RedirectToAction("index", db.EMPs.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'shanuMVCUserRoles.Models.Abstract', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'shanuMVCUserRoles.ViewModels.AbstractFormViewModel'. Throwing Error

Comment: Are you passing direct Model , Here it is IEnumerable List , check again in your code what data you are passing